# Calc 1 : maximum and minimum values : finding t in this equation(confused about what I did vs. what my teacher did)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Calculus 1: Section 4.1 Maximum and Minimum Values

Question: Find the critical numbers of the function
$$f(t) = 2\cos(t) + \sin^2 (t).$$

What I'm stuck with about the questions is after getting the equation $$-2\sin(t) + 2\sin(t)\cos(t) = 0,$$ I added $2\sin(t)$ to both sides and solved it for $t$, in order to find the critical numbers. I got $cos(t) = 1$ which I know that $t = 0$ would be the only critical number for this equation.

But my teacher did something different: $$-2\sin t(1 - \cos t) = 0$$ and got different results (2 critical numbers).
Can you please explain why my solution doesn't work, and his is correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You didn't solve for the case that $\sin t$ equaled $0.$  Not sure exactly what you did, but did you try to divide both sides by $\sin t$?   You can only do that if $\sin t \ne 0$

Comment: Moral (based on the answer of @DavidRaveh): Never divide by a variable quantity that *might* equal zero. Instead, put all terms on one side of the equation and *factor* that quantity out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went from
$$\sin t=\sin t \cos t$$
to
$$1=\cos t.$$
In doing so, you assumed you could divide by $\sin t$; but you can't do so if $\sin t=0$ ! So we have two types of solutions: Case 1: $\sin t=0$, Case 2: $\cos t=1$.

Comment: how did you get  sint=0

Comment: @JiaoCtagon the equation was $\sin t=\sin t \cos t$, which is clearly true whenever $\sin t=0$. The point is that this solution was lost when dividing by $\sin t$.